# Why is DISTINCT on 3 identical values so slow?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, profiler

I have a performance issue that I cannot understand in on of my queries. The query I am executing is the following:

```
SELECT UNIQUE GROUP_ID
  FROM pos, TABLE (t_type(12984918, 12984919, 12984917))
  WHERE pos.pos_id = COLUMN_VALUE AND GROUP_ID <> 0;

1 row returned in 99 ms
```

You might think that 83 ms is fine, but what really puzzles me is that removing `UNIQUE` makes the query a LOT faster even when there are only 3 duplicate values:

```
SELECT GROUP_ID
  FROM pos, TABLE (t_type(12984918, 12984919, 12984917))
  WHERE pos.pos_id = COLUMN_VALUE AND GROUP_ID <> 0;

3 rows returned in 0.048 ms
```

Is oracle really taking almost 100ms just to reduce a set of 3 elements to a single value? That seemed crazy to me, so I started doing some investigation and fetched the execution plan with `TKPROF`.

```
SELECT UNIQUE GROUP_ID
  FROM pos, TABLE (t_type(12984918, 12984919, 12984917))
 WHERE pos.pos_id = COLUMN_VALUE AND GROUP_ID <> 0

call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          2          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        1      0.00       0.09          0          8          0           1
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        3      0.00       0.10          0         10          0           1

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 58  
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
         1          1          1  HASH UNIQUE (cr=8 pr=0 pw=0 time=99258 us cost=31 size=3892 card=139)
         3          3          3   NESTED LOOPS  (cr=8 pr=0 pw=0 time=84 us)
         3          3          3    NESTED LOOPS  (cr=5 pr=0 pw=0 time=59 us cost=30 size=3892 card=139)
         3          3          3     COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=7 us cost=29 size=16336 card=8168)
         3          3          3     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN IU_POS_POS_ID (cr=5 pr=0 pw=0 time=31 us cost=0 size=0 card=1)(object id 20684)
         3          3          3    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID POS (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=12 us cost=0 size=26 card=1)
```

Well, it really looks like Oracle is taking 99 milliseconds to reduce 3 identical values into a single one, using the `HASH UNIQUE` operation. That actually STILL seems crazy. That should barely be noticeable. So I starter looking for an alternative. It turns out that Oracle can also use the `SORT UNIQUE` operation to implement `DISTINCT`. I also found out that I can force oracle to not use `HASH UNIQUE` by doing:

```
ALTER SESSION SET "_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled" = true;
```

An now, my query runs in 0.48ms! That's a 2000x improvement! WTF! Here's the execution plan that shows it's using `SORT UNIQUE`:

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        2      0.00       0.00          0          4          0           0
Execute      2      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        2      0.00       0.00          0         16          0           2
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        6      0.00       0.00          0         20          0           2

Misses in library cache during parse: 2
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 58  
Number of plan statistics captured: 2

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
         1          1          1  SORT UNIQUE (cr=8 pr=0 pw=0 time=48 us cost=30 size=28 card=1)
         3          3          3   NESTED LOOPS  (cr=8 pr=0 pw=0 time=35 us)
         3          3          3    NESTED LOOPS  (cr=5 pr=0 pw=0 time=26 us cost=29 size=28 card=1)
         3          3          3     COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=2 us cost=29 size=6 card=3)
         3          3          3     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN IU_POS_POS_ID (cr=5 pr=0 pw=0 time=17 us cost=0 size=0 card=1)(object id 20684)
         3          3          3    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID POS (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=7 us cost=0 size=26 card=1)

********************************************************************************
```

OK, so now I'm thinking how can I force oracle to use SORT UNIQUE without touching the session parameters. Turns out I can just add an `ORDER BY` clause, and speedup my query.

```
SELECT UNIQUE GROUP_ID
  FROM pos, TABLE (t_type(12984918, 12984919, 12984917))
 WHERE pos.pos_id = COLUMN_VALUE AND GROUP_ID <> 0
 ORDER BY GROUP_ID;
```

So basically I've solved my problem (if you can call that kind of hack "solving a problem"), but I'm still puzzled.

**So here are the question:**

- Why is Oracle choosing `HASH UNIQUE` over `SORT UNIQUE` ?
- Why is `HASH UNIQUE` so slow when there are only 3 records to hash?
- Is there a better way to hint oracle to use `SORT UNIQUE` over `HASH UNIQUE`?

Comment: Try a hint: `SELECT /*+ cardinality( x, 3 ) */ UNIQUE ....... pos, TABLE (t_type(12984918, 12984919, 12984917)) X` - note X alias after the table function. Could you also post "normal" Explain plans ? Plans from TK-Prof can be sometimes wrong. Please also add a new tag to your question ==> [micro-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/micro-optimization/info) ==> `However, micro-optimization carries the connotation of a disproportionate amount of effort being expended to extract relatively small improvements.`

Comment: I'm not sure that your session setting actually made the difference here - looks like cardinality feedback is in operation (first trace shows a cardinality estimate of 8168 which is probably a default number for `TABLE()`-type row sources (`COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=7 us cost=29 size=16336 card=8168)`) versus the second trace which shows a cardinality estimate of 3 (`COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=2 us cost=29 size=6 card=3)`).

Comment: More info: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/collection-costs/

Comment: @krokodilko It's not micro optimization when it's in the critical path of your application AND its part of the top consumer procedure :-)

Comment: Comparing such small execution times can be tricky.  It's very easy for caching or system activity to influence the results.  Before you read too much into this, I'd recommend running the two queries many times, alternating the queries, throw out the highs and lows, and averaging the results.

Comment: @JonHeller This is actually reproducable. The average over a few hundred executions more or less match these results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is Oracle choosing HASH UNIQUE over SORT UNIQUE?

Your first tkprof results show much higher (expected?) cardinality for the `TABLE` iterator. Oracle is optimizing for many more than three rows.

> Why is HASH UNIQUE so slow when there are only 3 records to hash?

Hash unique will need to build a hash table no matter how many elements are being hashed. Presumably the size of the hash table will be smaller for fewer elements, but again the cardinality estimate is such that Oracle is going to build a bigger hash table.

> Is there a better way to hint oracle to use SORT UNIQUE over HASH UNIQUE?

I would try hinting the cardinality on the table operator.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to hint oracle to use SORT UNIQUE over HASH
>   UNIQUE?

I´d check how are the table and index stats are gathered. They are used by oracle optimizer in order to build effective access plans.

Comment: Gathering stats on tables and indexes won't do any good for a row source based on a `TABLE()` operator.